# Google Play Store : How to upload more APKs to support different CPU architectures

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api

I want to Support different CPU architectures with each APK (such as for ARM, x86, and MIPS). How do I upload more APKs, I've switched to advanced mode, but the **Upload new APK to Alpha** button replaces the previous APK.

**Attached is how my console looks in the APK section.**

[image]

Will appreciate your help.

**For Reference, Here's my gradle :**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app_id_here"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        jackOptions {
            enabled false
            additionalParameters('jack.incremental': 'true')
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize '4096m'
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a', 'armeabi'
            universalApk false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this Article. Publishing multiple APKs on Google play https://blog.mindorks.com/publishing-multiple-apks-on-google-play-b06bb9078aae#.qqr2yqjfv

Navigate to the “APK” section of your app and hit “Switch to advanced mode” in the top right.

There You’ll notice the “upload new APK to production” button moving down and extra actions coming up on screen.

Now in advanced mode the console accepts multiple APKs on the same track, just hit the “upload new APK” button and follow the process one by one as in simple mode and click “save draft”.The console will show a relatively less number of compatible devices but don’t worry, because it shows devices compatible to only that specific ABI.

Comment: Accepted your answer, but it will later be down-voted. Please copy the important parts from that link and put them on this answer.

Answer (score -1):

You need to build multiple apks to upload on play store.

```
android {
  ...
  splits {

    // Configures multiple APKs based on ABI.
    abi {

      // Enables building multiple APKs per ABI.
      enable true

      // By default all ABIs are included, so use reset() and include to specify that we only
      // want APKs for x86, armeabi-v7a, and mips.

      // Resets the list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for to none.
      reset()

      // Specifies a list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for.
      include "x86", "armeabi-v7a", "mips"

      // Specifies that we do not want to also generate a universal APK that includes all ABIs.
      universalApk false
    }
  }
}
```

Configure your gradle as shown above.
Then upload it. This is useful if you want to upload for a limited audience to your app.
If you want to give access to all user you don't need any such configuration.

Comment: Yes my gradle is like that, Android Studio exports several APKs when I do `generate signed APKs`. What do you mean by "Then upload it"? You mean upload the APK?

Comment: I've added gradle, please check it out.