# How to install a specific APK on my device

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk

I do not use Android Studio but I do everything from the command line. I am building different APKs for different architectures so my `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
...
splits {

// Configures multiple APKs based on ABI.
abi {

  // Enables building multiple APKs per ABI.
  enable true

  // By default all ABIs are included, so use reset() and include to specify that we only
  // want APKs for x86, armeabi-v7a, and mips.

  // Resets the list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for to none.
  reset()

  // Specifies a list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for.
  include "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"

  // Specifies that we do not want to also generate a universal APK that includes all ABIs.
  universalApk false
 }
}
```

I then use the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41759623/google-play-store-how-to-upload-more-apks-to-support-different-cpu-architectur) to assign different version codes to the individual APKs.

This all works fine except that when I say

```
./gradlew tasks
```

there is only one task named `installRelease`. Running this task will then automatically choose an appropriate APK and install it.

However, I'd like to test the individual APKs separately, i.e. on my 64-bit Android device I'd first like to test `armeabi`, then `armeabi-v7a`, and finally `arm64-v8a`. When running `installRelease`, however, gradle will always automatically install `arm64-v8a`. So how can I force gradle to install a specific architecture?

Previously, I was using this code in `build.gradle` instead of the `splits` code shown above:

```
productFlavors {
    arm7 {
        // in the future, ndk.abiFilter might also work
        ndk {
            abiFilter 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
    }
    arm8 {
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
        }
    }        
    arm {
       ndk {
            abiFilter 'armeabi'
        }
    }
}
```

When using this code, gradle offered individual tasks named `installArmRelease`, `installArm7Release`, and `installArm8Release` which was exactly what I was looking for but I had to drop this code because I didn't find a way to use it alongside the code that generates different version codes for the individual APKs as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41759623/google-play-store-how-to-upload-more-apks-to-support-different-cpu-architectur).

Comment: _" I didn't find a way to use it alongside the code that generates different version codes for the individual APKs"_. Adding a `versionCode` field inside a product flavor definition works fine for me, or are you referring to something else?

Comment: Oh great, I didn't know I could just specifiy `versionCode` inside the `productFlavors` definition. I just tested it and it works fine and it is a much easier solution than the one described in the post linked to in my OP. Thanks!